# How to write new DAG with DataBricks API

Tags: databricks, directed-acyclic-graphs, databricks-rest-api, databricks-workflows

Using the DataBricks API from Python, how can I clone a template DAG with some minor replacements?

For example:

A template DAG contains some fields named like “template” and in the clone I want then to be “stage”. The newly cloned DAG and its tasks would have the same settings including dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use [Get Single Job API](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/jobs/get) call to obtain a configuration of a given job, manipulate job's configuration is is returned as a `settings` block to change necessary parameters, and then create a new job with [Create Job API](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/jobs/create) using the `settings` payload.

But instead of using APIs directly it's better to adopt new [Databricks SDK for Python](https://pypi.org/project/databricks-sdk/), that simplifies working with APIs, providing authentication, etc.  There are multiple examples of using SDK in its documentation.

Comment: I can clone a job with the sdk but is there a better way to clone a DAG (possibly of more DAGs) instead of having to navigate all the subjobs? I.e. by giving the sdk library just the highest level job id?